# Storing customisable quiz questions and answers in a .txt file using PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays, text

I have a customisable quiz site, where the user can input questions and answers. My first PHP file takes the inputted information and generates a quiz page. The answers are in hidden text box. A second PHP then compares the inputted radio button to the hidden text box to see if the user is correct and gives a score in relation to that. I would like to store the questions and answers in a .txt file which could then be accessed by other users, unfortunately as part of the project we are not able to use MySQL. Hopefully I am being clear, I have tried to go about this many ways but all have broken my code. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

My code is below:

INITIAL HTML:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>


</head>

<body>

<form action="actions.php" method="post">
<strong>Question 1:</strong> <input name="q1" type="text" /> <br />
Answer 1: <br />
<input name="a11" type="text" /><input name="1" type="radio" value="1.1" /><br />
Answer 2: <br />
<input name="a12" type="text" /><input name="1" type="radio" value="1.2" /><br />
Answer 3: <br />
<input name="a13" type="text" /><input name="1"type="radio" value="1.3"  /><br />
Answer 4: <br />
<input name="a14" type="text" /><input name="1" type="radio" value="1.4" />
<br /><br />


<strong>Question 2:</strong> <input name="q2" type="text" /> <br />
Answer 1: <br />
<input name="a21" type="text" /><input name="2" type="radio" value="2.1" /><br />
Answer 2: <br />
<input name="a22" type="text" /><input name="2" type="radio" value="2.2" /><br />
Answer 3: <br />
<input name="a23" type="text" /><input name="2"type="radio" value="2.3"  /><br />
Answer 4: <br />
<input name="a24" type="text" /><input name="2" type="radio" value="2.4" />
<br /><br />

<strong>Question 3:</strong> <input name="q3" type="text" /> <br />
Answer 1: <br />
<input name="a31" type="text" /><input name="3" type="radio" value="3.1" /><br />
Answer 2: <br />
<input name="a32" type="text" /><input name="3" type="radio" value="3.2" /><br />
Answer 3: <br />
<input name="a33" type="text" /><input name="3"type="radio" value="3.3"  /><br />
Answer 4: <br />
<input name="a34" type="text" /><input name="3" type="radio" value="3.4" />


<input name="" type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
```

FIRST PHP:

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="actions2.php" method="post">
<strong><?php echo $_POST["q1"];?></strong>
<br /><br />
<?php



echo $_POST["a11"]."<input name='newa1' type='radio' value='1.1' />"."<br />".$_POST["a12"]."<input name='newa1' type='radio' value='1.2' />"."<br />".$_POST["a13"]."<input name='newa1' type='radio' value='1.3' />"."<br />".$_POST["a14"]."<input name='newa1' type='radio' value='1.4' />"."<br />";

echo "<br /><br />"

?>

<strong><?php echo $_POST["q2"];?></strong>
<br><br>
<?php



echo $_POST["a21"]."<input name='newa2' type='radio' value='2.1' />"."<br />".$_POST["a22"]."<input name='newa2' type='radio' value='2.2' />"."<br />".$_POST["a23"]."<input name='newa2' type='radio' value='2.3' />"."<br />".$_POST["a24"]."<input name='newa2' type='radio' value='2.4' />"."<br />";

echo "<br /><br />"

?>

<strong><?php echo $_POST["q3"];?></strong>
<br><br>
<?php



echo $_POST["a31"]."<input name='newa3' type='radio' value='3.1' />"."<br />".$_POST["a32"]."<input name='newa3' type='radio' value='3.2' />"."<br />".$_POST["a33"]."<input name='newa3' type='radio' value='3.3' />"."<br />".$_POST["a34"]."<input name='newa3' type='radio' value='3.4' />"."<br />";

echo "<br /><br />"



?>



<input name="result1" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_POST['1']; ?>">
<input name="result2" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_POST['2']; ?>">
<input name="result3" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_POST['3']; ?>">



<input name="" type="submit" />

</form>



<br /><br />
</body>
</html>
```

SECOND PHP:

```
<?php




$correctAnswer1 = $_POST['result1'];
$newAnswer1 = $_POST['newa1'];
$correctAnswer2 = $_POST['result2'];
$newAnswer2 = $_POST['newa2'];
$correctAnswer3 = $_POST['result3'];
$newAnswer3 = $_POST['newa3'];
$score = 0;

if($newAnswer1 == $correctAnswer1) {
    $score++;
}
if($newAnswer2 == $correctAnswer2) {
    $score++;
}

if($newAnswer3 == $correctAnswer3) {
    $score++;
}

if ($score >= 2)
{
    echo "Congratulations, you did well. You got ".$score;
}
else if ($score == 1)
{
    echo "Only one, poor show";
}
else 
{
    echo "YOU GOT ZERO YOU SHITE";
}
?>
```

Comment: no excuses to to use a db

Comment: Sidenotes: A few things. `<input name="1" type="radio" value="1.1" />` etc. input variables cannot start with a number, plus your values having dots inside, which could be interpreted as a mathematics-related value. Plus, if you're going to use text files and that you're able to use `.htaccess` on your server (apparently nginx cannot use .htaccess) to protect them from prying eyes.

Comment: Also, leaving your submit button with `name=""` could play tricks on you. Although I've never seen a case like it and if it would. It's best to actually name it, just in case. `<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />`

Comment: I realise that syntax is not ideal, but as I am just testing this site (and on a side note, it works perfectly). As I said on the answer below, we are limited to HTML and PHP in our brief and are permitted to use .txt files.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure what you wanted, but if you need a way to store the questions and answers you could look into XML or JSON.

PHP should have libraries to encode/decode both of them

Comment: Unfortunately,restrictions of the brief limit me to PHP and HTML alone, databases are not permitted.

Comment: @GreenEggs_: This answer doesn't mention databases anywhere.

Comment: If you consider XML and JSON a "database" then you should consider a .txt file a database too.

Comment: Sorry, I shouldn't have mentioned databases. I have just been repeatedly told to use "databases" when we are restricted to HTML, PHP and .txt files.

Comment: Then use `json_encode()` and save that output to a .txt file.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I have understood the question pretty well, but this is how you store in a .txt file using php.
https://www.php.net/file_put_contents also take a look at this http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_fwrite.asp